# Is in bad condition the same meaning as bent out of shape?

Tags: american-english

Is in bad condition the same meaning as bent out of shape ?

Comment: "in bad condition" is a little more bleak than "bent out of shape," which slightly suggests that there is hope to get things back on the track with some effort. "in bad condition" is more hopeless than "bent out of shape."

Comment: I think maybe you mean "out of shape", not "bent out of shape".

Answer (score 2):

No.

Despite what it sounds like, "bent out of shape" is generally used not to describe the health of a person or the integrity of an object.  Instead, as defined by [oxforddictionaries.com](https://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/bent-out-of-shape), it means:

> Angry or agitated

Answer (score 0):

The phrase, "bent out of shape", can be interpreted literally, or figuratively, depending on the context. If these phrases refer to an inanimate object, they could be saying the same thing. Most people would probably consider an object that is bent out of its original shape to be "in bad condition".

If the phrases are applied to a person, they have different meanings. "Bent out of shape" means that the person is angry, or agitated. "In bad condition" can mean that the person is physically, mentally, or emotionally unwell.

Comment: After reading @Drew's comment above, it does seem like you meant "out of shape". In this case, the two phrases could both refer to a person who does not exercise. So, they would mean the same thing. Although "in bad condition" is a little awkward. Most would say, "out of shape."